# Get the number of certain search result on SERP with iMacro

Tags: google-search, imacros

I scrape with iMacro Universal Search results on Google SERP pages. Those are mostly news and images. I find the `div class` (for news) and `div id` (for images), then filter the export and write URLs into the export file. Names of classes and ids aren't often modified by Google, so the relation to them is stable and cushy enough.

This works, like it should, independently of where on the SERP the onebox (div with news or images) appears.The onebox however can appear on different SERP locations: before the first organic result, between the first and second, second and third and so on.

The question: Universal Search results, specially news, images and local pack, can appear on different places on SERP: before the first organic result, between the first and second, second and third, nine and ten, like on the screenshot:
[image]

I want that my iMacro **tracks the place of onebox implementation** and writes it into the second column of the same file, where the ranking URLs are written. I. e. if news appear before the first organic result, i want to get 1, if between the first and second - 2, between nine and ten - 10.

Here is on of my iMacros, for the newsbox:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=NAME:q CONTENT=iphone
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=TYPE:submit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"mnr-c _yE" EXTRACT=HTM
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/href="([^\'\"]+)/g);")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=links.csv
```

**Edit:**
Edit and used the javascript code, which looks for me now like:
var macro;

```
macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:"r" EXTRACT=HTM";

iimPlay(macro)


table=iimGetLastExtract();

table=table.split("<tr>");

for(var t=0;t<table.length;t++)
{

if(table[t].indexOf('class="mnr-c _yE"')!=-1)
{
var position=t;
position++;
break;
}

}

alert(position);
```

But get an error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line NaN (Error code: -991)
```

Each search result is placed inside of `<div class="g"></div>`, so on SERP with 10 organic search results are 10 such `div`s. It could be the method how to get the number of search result, after or before which appears the onebox - to count, how many `div class="g"` appeared before. But i miss a skill to code this:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire macro looks like:

```
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=NAME:q CONTENT=iphone
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=TYPE:submit

WAIT SECONDS=3
SET S "(function(){var elsH3 = window.document.getElementsByTagName('h3');"
ADD S "for (i = 0; i < elsH3.length; i++)"
ADD S "elsH3[i].setAttribute('searchnumber', i + 1);})()"
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"mnr-c _yE" EXTRACT=HTM
SET oneBox EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/href="([^\'\"]+)/g);")
SET !EXTRACT NULL

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:"r" EXTRACT=HTM
SET searchNumberBefore EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/searchnumber=\"(.*?)\"/)[1];")

SET !EXTRACT "after {{searchNumberBefore}}[EXTRACT]{{oneBox}}"
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=links.csv
```

---

Here is my idea:

```
SET S "(function(){var elsH3 = window.document.getElementsByTagName('h3');"
ADD S "for (i = 0; i < elsH3.length; i++)"
ADD S "elsH3[i].setAttribute('searchnumber', i + 1);})()"
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"mnr-c _yE" EXTRACT=HTM
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:"r" EXTRACT=HTM
SET searchNumberBefore EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/searchnumber=\"(.*?)\"/)[1];")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:"r" EXTRACT=HTM
SET searchNumberAfter EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/searchnumber=\"(.*?)\"/)[1];")
PROMPT "between {{searchNumberBefore}} and {{searchNumberAfter}}"
```

Improve this code and adjust it to your macro.

Comment: it works already nearly so, as it should, with one little exception: it relates on extraction to the Google's own attribute `searchnumber`, but Google give forthcoming numbers to all divs on the SERP, and i get results like `between 214 and 215`. The ampunt of searchnumbers on each SERP page is different, so it isn't possible to calculate based on them. Is it possible to relate only on `<div class="g"></div>`, which are maximally 10 on SERP page?

Comment: `Searchnumbers` are attributes which are set by myself on the 3rd line of the macro (they aren't Google ones). I don't know why you get a prompt like `between 214 and 215`. Provide the page link where that happens.

Comment: Haha! I'v just looked into SERP source code and thought, wow, Google gives numbers to every div on the page:):) I've modified your code a little bit to relate not on `getElementsByTagName`, but on `getElementsByClassName`, and now i get correct numbers, at least the needful first number, after which appears the OneBox. Could you join your code with the first iMacro part above in the question, so the iMacro writes into one column the numbers from the Prompt, and into second column extracted URLs?

Comment: See the updated code and correct it to your needs, as you wrote before.

Comment: Absolutely! Ha, you realized this with before/after too:) i changed it locally, then look into your post, and this is changed too. My bounty for you will be  enabled only after 23 hours. That was a real ninja trick from you!

Comment: I'm glad that at last you got what needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Did u try using JavaScript.

If you get the whole table and store it using iimGetLastExtract(), you can store data into variable and split on table row tag. Like bellow,

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:something EXTRACT=HTM";

iimPlay(macro)


table=iimGetLastExtract();

table=table.split("<tr>");

for(var t=0;t<table.length;t++)
{

if(table[t].indexOf("someHtmlTag")!=-1)
{
var position=t;
position++;
break;
}

}

alert(position);
```

I didn't quite understand the question but I hope this helps.

EDIT: USING FIREBUG CHECK THE HTML PROPERTY OF THE NEWS ONBOX. THEN IN INDEXOF PART OF CODE PUT THAT PROPERTY. FOR EXAMPLE class="OneBox" ...

Comment: if(table[t].indexOf('class="mnr-c _yE"')!=-1)
Edit this part and insert ' like in example above.

Comment: your macroscripts.org/contact-us/ seems to be hacked: form doesn't work and the source code is full of ad links

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104115/discussion-between-chilly-bang-and-macroscripts).